# What is happening here in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, private, encapsulation, reinterpret-cast

I was reading this excellent article [**Uses & Abuses of Access Rights**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm). I didn't understand following example from that.

File: x.h

```
class X 
{ 
public:
  X() : private_(1) { /*...*/ }

  template<class T>
  void f( const T& t ) { /*...*/ }

  int Value() { return private_; }

private: 
  int private_; 
};
```

File: break.cpp

```
#include "x.h"
#include <iostream>
class BaitAndSwitch
    // hopefully has the same data layout as X
{   // so we can pass him off as one
  public:
  int notSoPrivate;
};

void f( X& x )
{
  // evil laughter here
  (reinterpret_cast<BaitAndSwitch&>(x)).notSoPrivate = 2;
}
int main()
{
    X x;
    std::cout<<x.Value()<<'\n';
    f(x);
    std::cout<<x.Value()<<'\n';
}
```

How this program works? What's actually happening in global function f()? Please someone clearly explain how the value of private variable gets changed?

Why herb sutter said that the object layouts of X and BaitAndSwitch are not guaranteed to be the same, although in practice they probably always will be?
Is this program well defined?

Comment: I think that `reinterpret_cast`ing a pointer to a pointer to a “wrong” object invokes undefined behavior.  This UB might turn out to do just what you wanted but it's pointless to reason about and dangerous to rely on it.

Comment: This program *doesn't* work; its behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen, and you're seeing a particular realization of "anything".

Comment: @KerrekSB: It produces expected output on my local machine. What the lang. specification says about this?

Comment: He probably said that the layouts aren't guaranteed to be the same because they aren't. "Probably will in practice" is not a guarantee.

Comment: It overrides private field by blindly casting one class with only one int to another class with only one int as well. Compiler gets a command: "put 2 into field of the BaitAndSwitch class's object". Because  at the runtime there is no classes, compiler translates this to "write 2 into memory by address <x> with offset <0>", zero becase it is first field of the class in both classes.

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Even "your expectation" is a realization of "anything", quite possibly the most dangerous one of all.

Comment: @PravasiMeet what is the behavior you expect? The C++ standard does not specify what will happen in these circumstances, so there's no behavior you should expect.

Comment: The result will change if you add of remove or rearrange fields or add virtual members in class X.

Comment: @Satus: Yes, interesting point. Thanks. I added virtual function in class X & now value of private variable remains unchanged. Why? Is it because of secret addition of vptr in class X so its object layout is now different from BaitAndSwitch class?

Comment: For it to work, the classes/struct need to have the same layout. Adding a virtual function changes the layout because it adds a hidden pointer to a vtable (just the first virtual function added does this -- all following virtual functions reuse the same pointer).

Comment: @PravasiMeet Because if your class has virual functions, a virtual table for your class will be created in the memory, and every object of your class will store a pointer to that table as a first invisible member. If you want more details of why this is needed and how it works, google "c++ dynamic polymorphous".

Comment: To add to what @KerrekSB says, the article  uses the words *illegal* and *undefined* several times. So I think the article is clear that this is undefined behavior and therefore we can have no expectations as to the results.

Comment: The page you quoted itself tells whats going on: 
`The code in Example 3 is illegal for two reasons:
a) The object layouts of X and BaitAndSwitch are not guaranteed to be the same, although in practice they probably always will be.
b) The results of the reinterpret_cast are undefined, although most compilers will let you try to use the resulting reference in the way the hacker intended.
`

Comment: The article is also [referenced a few times in previous SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+%22Uses+and+Abuses+of+Access+Rights%22) have you read those first?

Comment: Well, it is undefined from the C++ language and compiler point of view, it is not (in this case) undefined to programmer. Though yes, never use this type of hacks in real programs, it is only good for fun.

Comment: IMO if it doesn't work for you, you might want to rethink your choice of compiler. Because yours is either completely insane or very clever in some nonobvious way. In any case, you can always get at private variables if you really want to, and it should be possible to get at it in a defined way too (inspect your layout of ints, use a char pointer, convert char pointer array to int as per your discovered int layout).

Comment: @PSkocik `#define private public` works better, just sayin' xD

Comment: It would help if you told us what exactly you don't understand. After all, everything *is* explained on the page you are quoting.

Comment: @Satus: The article already shows this trick. See section "Criminal #2: The Pickpocket".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casting is remapping the private area into a public one in a new structure.  This behavior is not guaranteed to work (though it is probably stable) as the layout of structures internally is not set.

It is really no different than grabbing a pointer and writing something into it, although it is done is a bit more precise way.

Answer (score 0):

See [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast]

You're basically telling the compiler that your object in fact is a `BaitAndSwitch` object, and it will actually do what you told it :-)